# conditional downloading page contents (js, css)

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache

How to tell the browser that if css or js files are in `not modified (303)` state than load it from cache otherwise get it from server?

I have this htacces so far, but this rule has to be overridden if there is any change:

```
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 6 MONTH
<FilesMatch "\.(png|ico|css|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

You can use the modified time instead of access time in the Expires rule.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|ico|css|js)$">
ExpiresDefault M604800
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I have tested this but not modified files aren't loaded from cache.(Only the files with OK state)